# Zoom-able CarouselView in Xamarin.form

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, carousel, zooming

I'm using carousel view to display a number of images, changeable upon sliding. The problem I'm having is that these images are not zoom-able. Is there any way to enable zooming within carousel view? Thanks.

Comment: So, what have you done so far?

Comment: implemented the carousel view. Its all working expect there's no zooming.

Comment: @Ahsanzz1This is the expected behavior, there is no zooming in the stock CarouselView. Or did you implement anything to employ zooming?

Comment: @PaulKertscher I haven't implemented anything for zooming. I was wondering what are my options for such functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the First Thing first Carousel View is not  a gud thing which you want to make zoom (for Practical Case) 
and as client demands out of the Galaxy things so you can make things work out with some logic

**1st Way:**

Create a Class Name ZoomImage in Your Shared Xamarin.forms Solution and Add this code in it

```
public class ZoomImage : Image {
  private const double MIN_SCALE = 1;
  private const double MAX_SCALE = 4;
  private const double OVERSHOOT = 0.15;
  private double StartScale;
  private double LastX, LastY;

  public ZoomImage() {
    var pinch = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
    pinch.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
    GestureRecognizers.Add(pinch);

    var pan = new PanGestureRecognizer();
    pan.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
    GestureRecognizers.Add(pan);

    var tap = new TapGestureRecognizer { NumberOfTapsRequired = 2 };
    tap.Tapped += OnTapped;
    GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);

    Scale = MIN_SCALE;
    TranslationX = TranslationY = 0;
    AnchorX = AnchorY = 0;
  }

  protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint) {
    Scale = MIN_SCALE;
    TranslationX = TranslationY = 0;
    AnchorX = AnchorY = 0;
    return base.OnMeasure(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
  }

  private void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Scale > MIN_SCALE) {
      this.ScaleTo(MIN_SCALE, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
      this.TranslateTo(0, 0, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
    }
    else {
      AnchorX = AnchorY = 0.5; //TODO tapped position
      this.ScaleTo(MAX_SCALE, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
    }
  }

  private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e) {
    if (Scale > MIN_SCALE)
      switch (e.StatusType) {
        case GestureStatus.Started:
          LastX = TranslationX;
          LastY = TranslationY;
          break;
        case GestureStatus.Running:
          TranslationX = Clamp(LastX + e.TotalX * Scale, -Width / 2, Width / 2);
          TranslationY = Clamp(LastY + e.TotalY * Scale, -Height / 2, Height / 2);
          break;
      }
  }

  private void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e) {
    switch (e.Status) {
      case GestureStatus.Started:
        StartScale = Scale;
        AnchorX = e.ScaleOrigin.X;
        AnchorY = e.ScaleOrigin.Y;
        break;
      case GestureStatus.Running:
        double current = Scale + (e.Scale - 1) * StartScale;
        Scale = Clamp(current, MIN_SCALE * (1 - OVERSHOOT), MAX_SCALE * (1 + OVERSHOOT));
        break;
      case GestureStatus.Completed:
        if (Scale > MAX_SCALE)
          this.ScaleTo(MAX_SCALE, 250, Easing.SpringOut);
        else if (Scale < MIN_SCALE)
          this.ScaleTo(MIN_SCALE, 250, Easing.SpringOut);
        break;
    }
  }

  private T Clamp<T>(T value, T minimum, T maximum) where T : IComparable {
    if (value.CompareTo(minimum) < 0)
      return minimum;
    else if (value.CompareTo(maximum) > 0)
      return maximum;
    else
      return value;
  }
}
```

and now In Xaml within carousel view Use Image Like This

```
<cv:CarouselView x:Name="itemPictureGallery"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                    <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate>
                          <local:image source="YOUR_PIC_SOURCE"  />
                         </DataTemplate>

                    </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                </cv:CarouselView>
```

Dont Forget to add nameSpace in Xamal

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YOUR_APP_NAME"
```

so this is how the image can zoom etiher

**Or Second Way is**

add an Item Tapped on carousel view and pass the picture source in command parameter and open a new page with that picture in it and apply zoom with in it

i use that logic for figure out my problem

Hope this Helps :)

Comment: Here I have one problem, I'm using carousel view to display a number of images, When i zoomin  one image after that swipe another image(background image showing), Please give me solution to resolve this issue

Comment: I want to zoom out when position change in carouselview. I am Create a Class Name ZoomImage. Example inside viewcell  like <Controls:ZoomImage x:Name="imgPicked"
                                                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                        Source="{Binding icon}"/>. you have any idea? still i am facing issue

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using

alexrainman/CarouselView for the carousal view.
https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView

and add Xamarin forms pinch gesture recognizer according to the forms sample to the image used in carousal view

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/pinch